# Kubernetes secret not creating in argo workflow

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, argo-workflows

I want to create a secret in my argo workflow but it does not create. If I run the workflow and I run the comman kubectl get secret -n argo-events the secret is not created

I am using shipwright for my build

I created a dag which is dependent on each other. After the secret is created the shipwright build calls the secret.

but the secret is not creating...

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: argo-service-sensor-with-dockerfile
  namespace: argo-events
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: deploy-service-with-dockerfile
      eventSourceName: deploy-service-with-dockerfile-event
      eventName: example
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: webhook-workflow-trigger
        k8s:
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          resource: workflows
          operation: create
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                generateName: service-workflow-with-dockerfile-
              spec:
                serviceAccountName: deployer-sa
                entrypoint: serviceWorkflow
                arguments:
                  parameters:
                    - name: repo_url
                      value: hello world
                    - name: cpu_limit
                      value: hello world
                    - name: git_branch
                      value: hello world
                    - name: username
                      value: hello world
                    - name: token
                      value: hello world
                templates:
                  - name: serviceWorkflow
                    inputs:
                      parameters:
                        - name: username
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.username}}"
                        - name: token
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.token}}"
                        - name: repo_url
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.repo_url}}"
                        - name: cpu_limit
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.cpu_limit}}"
                        - name: git_branch
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.git_branch}}"
                    dag:
                      tasks:
                        - name: createSecretForGithub
                          template: create-secret-for-github
                          arguments:
                            parameters:
                              - name: username
                                value: "{{inputs.parameters.username}}"
                              - name: token
                                value: "{{inputs.parameters.token}}"
                        - name: buildNodeServiceWorkflowWithDockerfile
                          template: build-node-with-dockerfile
                          arguments:
                            parameters:
                              - name: repo_url
                                value: "{{inputs.parameters.repo_url}}"
                              - name: cpu_limit
                                value: "{{inputs.parameters.cpu_limit}}"
                              - name: git_branch
                                value: "{{inputs.parameters.git_branch}}"
                          depends: createSecretForGithub.Succeeded
                        - name: showFailedMessage
                          template: build-failed
                          depends: buildNodeServiceWorkflowWithDockerfile.Failed
                        - name: deleteSecret
                          template: delete-secret
                          depends: buildNodeServiceWorkflowWithDockerfile.Succeeded
                        - name: curlAWebsite
                          template: curl-a-website
                          depends: deleteSecret.Succeeded

                  - name: create-secret-for-github
                    inputs:
                      parameters:
                        - name: username
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.username}}"
                        - name: token
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.token}}"
                    resource:
                      action: create
                      setOwnerReference: true
                      failureCondition: status.conditions.0.reason == Failed
                      successCondition: status.conditions.0.reason == Succeeded
                      manifest: |
                        apiVersion: v1
                        kind: Secret
                        metadata:
                          name: secret-git-basic-auth
                          namespace: argo-events
                          annotations:
                            build.shipwright.io/referenced.secret: "true"
                        type: kubernetes.io/basic-auth
                        stringData:
                          username: username
                          password: password
                  - name: build-node-with-dockerfile
                    inputs:
                      parameters:
                        - name: repo_url
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.repo_url}}"
                        - name: cpu_limit
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.cpu_limit}}"
                        - name: git_branch
                          value: "{{inputs.parameters.git_branch}}"
                    resource:
                      action: create
                      setOwnerReference: true
                      failureCondition: status.conditions.0.reason == Failed
                      successCondition: status.conditions.0.reason == Succeeded
                      manifest: |
                        apiVersion: shipwright.io/v1alpha1
                        kind: BuildRun
                        metadata:
                          generateName: buildpack-nodejs-buildrun-with-dockerfile-
                        spec:
                          buildSpec:
                            source:
                              url: "{{inputs.parameters.repo_url}}"
                              credentials:
                                name: secret-git-basic-auth
                            strategy:
                              name: kaniko
                              kind: ClusterBuildStrategy
                            output:
                              image: aws/demo-app:latest
                              credentials:
                                name: ecr-docker-configjson
                  - name: curl-a-website
                    container:
                      image: curlimages/curl:latest
                      command:
                        - "sh"
                      args:
                        - -c
                        - |
                          echo $(curl -d '{"bucketName":"node-app", "repoUrl": "git-url", "completedWebhook", "", "cpu_limit": "1"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://webhook.site/749f85b1-e5b6-4fa5-a7aa-7170dc1178ef)
                  - name: build-failed
                    container:
                      image: alpine:3.6
                      command: [sh, -c]
                      args: ['echo "the flakey container failed"']
                  - name: delete-secret
                    script:
                      image: debian:9.4
                      command: [bash]
                      source: |
                        cat /dev/urandom | od -N2 -An -i | awk -v f=1 -v r=100 '{printf "%i\n", f + r * $1 / 65536}'

          parameters:
            - src:
                dependencyName: deploy-service-with-dockerfile
                dataKey: body.repo_url
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.0.value
            - src:
                dependencyName: deploy-service-with-dockerfile
                dataKey: body.cpu_limit
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.1.value
            - src:
                dependencyName: deploy-service-with-dockerfile
                dataKey: body.git_branch
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.2.value
            - src:
                dependencyName: deploy-service-with-dockerfile
                dataKey: body.username
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.3.value
            - src:
                dependencyName: deploy-service-with-dockerfile
                dataKey: body.token
              dest: spec.arguments.parameters.4.value
```

This is my log

```
time="2023-09-23T12:27:19 UTC" level=info msg="Waiting for resource secret./secret-git-basic-auth in namespace argo-events resulte
d in retryable error: Neither success condition nor the failure condition has been matched. Retrying..."
time="2023-09-23T12:27:24 UTC" level=info msg="failure condition '{status.phase == [Failed]}' evaluated false"
time="2023-09-23T12:27:24 UTC" level=info msg="success condition '{status.phase == [Succeeded]}' evaluated false"
time="2023-09-23T12:27:24 UTC" level=info msg="0/1 success conditions matched"
time="2023-09-23T12:27:24 UTC" level=info msg="Waiting for resource secret./secret-git-basic-auth in namespace argo-events resulte
d in retryable error: Neither success condition nor the failure condition has been matched. Retrying..."
time="2023-09-23T12:27:29 UTC" level=info msg="failure condition '{status.phase == [Failed]}' evaluated false"
time="2023-09-23T12:27:29 UTC" level=info msg="success condition '{status.phase == [Succeeded]}' evaluated false"
time="2023-09-23T12:27:29 UTC" level=info msg="0/1 success conditions matched"
time="2023-09-23T12:27:29 UTC" level=info msg="Waiting for resource secret./secret-git-basic-auth in namespace argo-events resulte
d in retryable error: Neither success condition nor the failure condition has been matched. Retrying..."
```